# MS SQL: alter indexed view by including additional columns from new table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, pivot

I need to update existing MS SQL indexed view by including additional columns values from newly created table. 
Indexed view:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[MySelectionInfo]
  WITH schemabinding
  AS
    SELECT C.Id                                         id0,
           C.Code                                       Code1,
           C.Name                                       Name2,
           C.ProgramLevel                               Level3,
           C.Department                                 Department4,
           C.City                                       City10,
           C.STATE                                      State11,
           C.StartDate                                  StartDate12,
           C.Deadline                                   Deadline13,
           B.ID                                         Table_B_ID,
           A.Id                                        Table_A_ID

    FROM dbo.Table_A A
           INNER JOIN dbo.Table_B B ON A.id = B.Table_A_Id
           INNER JOIN dbo.Table_C C ON C.Table_B_Id = B.Id
```

New table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table_D] (
  [Id]               [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  [ModelName] [varchar](max)                    NOT NULL,
  [Table_C_Id]        [int]                             NOT NULL,
  [AttributeValue]   [varchar](max)                    NOT NULL,
  [CreatedDate]      [datetime]                        NOT NULL,
  [UpdatedDate]      [datetime]                        NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_Table_C_Id FOREIGN KEY (Table_C_Id) REFERENCES some_schema.dbo.[Table_C] (Id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

Data in the new table:
[image]

I want to include only some of the ModelName column values as a column names and AttributeValue as values in the `select * from [dbo].[MySelectionInfo]` result set:

[image]

I can achieve the desired result using the `PIVOT` function:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW [dbo].[MySelectionInfo]
  WITH schemabinding
  AS
    SELECT C.Id                                         id0,
           C.Code                                       Code1,
           C.Name                                       Name2,
           C.StartDate                                  StartDate12,
           C.Deadline                                   Deadline13,
           B.ID                                         Table_B_ID,
           A.Id                                        Table_A_ID
    FROM dbo.Table_A A
           INNER JOIN dbo.Table_B B ON A.id = B.Table_A_Id
           INNER JOIN dbo.Table_C C ON C.Table_B_Id = B.Id
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT PivotTable.Table_C_Id,
                             PivotTable.attribute1,
                             PivotTable.attribute2,
                             PivotTable.attribute3
                      FROM (SELECT Table_D.Table_C_Id,
                                   Table_D.ModelName,
                                   Table_D.AttributeValue
                            FROM dbo.Table_C
                                   INNER JOIN dbo.Table_D
                                     ON Table_C.Id = Table_D.Table_C_Id) AS sourceTable
                               PIVOT (
                                 Max(AttributeValue) FOR ModelName IN (attribute1, attribute2, attribute3)
                               ) AS PivotTable) dbo.Table_D D ON D.Table_C_Id = C.Id
```

**But**, after running the SQL statement above, I am not be able to create the clustered index for the view, because `LEFT` `JOIN`, `PIVOT`, `MAX` are prohibited to be used in the [indexed views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15).

**Question:** Is there any other solutions to achieve the desired result and still have an existing view as an Indexed view?

Comment: You could keep your existing indexed view and add the `LEFT JOIN` and `PIVOT`  to queries that use the indexed view (which could be encapsulated in a regular view).

Comment: @DanGuzman, thanks for response. I am not sure I fully understand you. According to MS SQL doc,  I can't reference other view from indexed view. Can you provide some sample? Thanks.

Comment: Short answer - no. But your original view is rather straight-forward and I have to question the utility of indexing it in the first place. And since you have now chosen an EAV approach, you should really research this choice and understand the pain you will endure from this point forward trying to turn that into usable and queryable information.

Comment: @SMor, the real view is much more complicated it comprise data from 7 tables. I just simplify it for the post here. Unfortunately, I am not able to do redesign it.

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, I'm not suggesting you change your existing indexed view. I suggest you specify your existing index view in the `FROM` clause of a new non-indexed view or query, and then add the `LEFT JOIN` to that query.

Comment: @DanGuzman, ohh you mean to create non-index view that contains `PIVOT` logic and do a left join with an existing indexed view, right?

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, correct. As you know, there are many restrictions with indexed views so the many disallowed constructs are a non-starter. But you can still leverage the performance benefit of materialization of the existing indexed view in the query.

Comment: @DanGuzman, cool. Performance was my next question. That is really cool it still be very fast, as currently there is ~200k records in the indexed view.

Comment: @I.Domshchikov, look at the actual plan to determine if/how the indexed view is used and consider indexes on the joined tables as well. You might need to add a `NOEXPAND` hint to use the indexed view.

Comment: @DanGuzman, your solution works for me. Can you please create an answer and I will mark it as solution to my issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if your **data allow it**, you could cross tab with case statements instead of PIVOTing:

```
/*
drop view dbo.mytestinfoview;
go
drop table dbo.Table1;
go
--*/

create table dbo.Table1
(
    id int,
    ModelName varchar(20),
    AttributeValue int
);


insert into dbo.Table1(id, ModelName, AttributeValue)
select distinct o.object_id, concat('attribute', v.id), o.attributevalue
from 
(
    select 
        object_id , 
        abs(checksum(newid())) % 2 as attributevalue
    from sys.objects
) as o
cross apply (values(1), (2), (3), (4)) as v(id)
go

create or alter view dbo.mytestinfoview
with schemabinding
as
    select id, count_big(*) as thecounter,
        sum(isnull(case ModelName when 'attribute1' then AttributeValue end, 0)) as attribute1,
        sum(isnull(case ModelName when 'attribute2' then AttributeValue else 0 end, 0)) as attribute2,
        sum(isnull(case ModelName when 'attribute3' then AttributeValue else 0 end, 0)) as attribute3
    from dbo.Table1
    group by id
go

create unique clustered index idx_v1 on dbo.mytestinfoview(id);
go

select * from dbo.mytestinfoview;
go
```