# Create indexed view from defined pivot table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, view, pivot-table

I have a requirement of creating a view for pivot table

This is my source table

[image]

According to my requirement I have created the following pivot table

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Date) 
                    from Salse_Data
                    group by Date
                    order by Date
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'SELECT Product,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Product, Date, Salse
                from Salse_Data
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Salse)
                for Date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
execute(@query);
```

Output is

[image]

I need to create an indexed view(Materialized View) above query
So i used procedure to create the view

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductSalse_By_Year_Proc_4]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Date) 
                    from Salse_Data
                    group by Date
                    order by Date
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

    set @query = 'CREATE VIEW abcd with schemabinding as  SELECT Product,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select Product, Date, Salse
                from Salse_Data
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(Salse)
                for Date in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
    EXECUTE(@query)
END
GO
```

this execuce without errors but not created the view.

Could you please help on this issue?

Comment: A view has rather strict [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) that must met to be indexed. Pivot is not allowed. So no - you cannot index this view.

Comment: Rather than a view, consider dropping, creating and indexing a table

Comment: you are SUMming, you could "pivot" with sum(isnull(case Date when yearx then Sales end, 0)) as yearx...etc
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070076/ms-sql-alter-indexed-view-by-including-additional-columns-from-new-table/59071263#59071263